# setting a multi index does not allow access using .loc?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]})
empty_row_index = ("zero_scan")
empty_row_df = pd.DataFrame({c: [None] for c in df.columns})
empty_row_df.index = [empty_row_index]
df2 = pd.concat([empty_row_df, df])result = df2.loc[df2.index[0], :]
```

works

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]})
empty_row_index = ("zero_scan",)
empty_row_df = pd.DataFrame({c: [None] for c in df.columns})
empty_row_df.index = [empty_row_index]
df2 = pd.concat([empty_row_df, df])result = df2.loc[df2.index[0], :]
```

key error.

Notice `"zero_scan"` vs `"zero_scan",`.

This is a test program, and I need the `"zero_scan",` version using multi index.

How to correct the access to the row by index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be *counterintuitive* but pandas unpacks a single tuple when this one is passed to [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) in order to match the corresponding MultiIndex levels (*1st element <> 1st-level, 2nd-element<> 2nd-level*). And since your `df2` has a **flat** index, the `KeyError` is trigerred.

As a solution, you need to enclose your tuple with square brackets `[]` or use a `slice` indexer :

```
# df2.index.nlevels shows `1`

# df2.index[0] is equal to ("zero_scan", )

result = df2.loc[[df2.index[0]], :] # or slice(df2.index[0])
```

Output :

```
print(result)
    
                 a     b
(zero_scan,)  None  None
```

Comment: **NB** : There is an ongoing recent issue (discussed here, [*GH54464*](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/54464)) regarding this matter.

Comment: what's NB? great answer

Comment: Just a note that I added to link the GitHub issue. Don't hesitate to check it out ;)

Comment: I mean what does NB mean?

Comment: A note, see [here](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/NB#:~:text=%E2%97%8A%20The%20abbreviation%20NB%20comes,which%20means%20%E2%80%9Cmark%20well.%E2%80%9D).